# Explain this function definition: function(struct net * const *pnet)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I was going through the linux kernel sources and found this function definition.

```
function(struct net * const *pnet)
```

Can somebody explain what does this mean. Is it a net* or net** or const net* or const net**?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In words: a (non-constant) pointer to a constant array of pointers to (non-constant) structs.

So, you can assign a different array:

```
pnet = myArrayOfStructs;
```

or you can change a struct:

```
pnet[k]->proc_inum = 17;
```

but you can't change a complete struct:

```
pnet[k] = &pnet[k+1]; // compiler error
```

Answer (score 6):

pnet is a pointer to a const point to a struct net (in a case like this, you just read from right to left from the name of the variable to the name of the type, reading `*` as "pointer).

Comment: Somewhere there is a really cool webpage which will translate crazy C syntax to English, like this. Does anyone know where that is?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: `cdecl.com`, if memory serves. Doing a quick check, that doesn't seem to be it though. Hmm...ah, here it is -- cdecl.org.

Comment: so does it mean that its a double pointer (pointer to a const pointer)? and can you guys tell what is its usage?

Comment: what I'm interested is the const part. double pointers are usually used to set a pointer in function. how does that change here if const is used?

Comment: cdecl.org... cool, never seen that before. Ironically, I pasted the OP's example there and it produced `syntax error`